# How to fix the error "Executable "zip" needed for creating OpenDocument files" when exporting Org mode document to OpenOffice?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, microsoft-windows

When I try to export an Org mode document to OpenOffice Document format, I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8625741/399457) suggested to use [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). So I

1. installed 7zip,
2. copied `7z.exe` and renamed the copy to `zip.exe`, and
3. added the path of 7zip (`C:\Program Files\7-Zip`) to `exec-path` (via `M-x customize-variable RET exec-path RET`).

But when I try to export my Org mode file to ODT with this setup, I get an error `Incorrect command line`, probably because 7zip uses different command line arguments than the `zip` program Org mode expects.

[image: Screenshot 2]

How can I fix this?

Comment: How about using `zip` instead of `7zip`?  Renaming a program from "orange" to "banana" does not make the program a 
"banana"; i.e., it is an "orange" disguised as a "banana" and your computer knows it and that is why it is saying "Error:  Incorrect command line".

Comment: Here is a link to a thread that seems applicable:  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-04/msg00423.html

Comment: @lawlist Where can I get that `zip` for Windows? Cygwin?

Comment: Have you already read through the linked thread and tried out the recommendations?  There are five (5) posts including the initial question in that thread ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short tutorial for all who want to use ODT export under Windows.

1. I downloaded :

[zip](https://fossies.org/windows/misc/zip300xn.zip/) and
[unzip](https://fossies.org/windows/misc/unz600xn.exe/)

2. Extracted zip300xn.zip in a folder `zip300xn` and executed unz600xn.exe in a folder `unz600xn`
3. Put those two folders in `C:\Program Files\zip300xn` and `C:\Program Files\unz600xn`.

I set the `exec-path` variable as shown below using `M-x customize-variable RET exec-path RET`.

[image: exec-path variable]

When I try to export an Org Mode document to OpenOffice.org, I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

Then I changed the paths in `exec-path` to the following:

[image: exec-path values 2]

Translation from German:

*Command `C:\Program`  is either spelled wrongly or could not be found.*

Then I moved `zip300xn` and `unz600xn` to `C:/EmacsInfrastructure` and set the `exec-path` variable accordingly.

Still no luck: `unzip.exe` could not be found in `C:/EmacsInfrastructure/zip300xn`.

Copied `unzip.exe` and `unzip.txt` from `EmacsInfrastructure\unz600xn` to `C:/EmacsInfrastructure/zip300xn`.

Then it worked.

Comment: In the second link to "2. unzip" you have to select the two files to download "unzip.exe" and "unzip.txt". First I downloaded "unz600xn.exe" and this did not work. Thanks for the Solution Dimitrii!